# Extraction of a common column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames, I need to extract data in Column_3 of the second dataframe DF2.

**Question 1:** How should I create "Column_3" from "Column_1" and "Column_2" of the first dataframe?

DF1 =

```
Column_1           Column_2          Column_3
Red Apple           small          Red Apple small
Green fruit         Large          Green fruit Large
Yellow Banana       Medium         Yellow Banana Medium
Pink Mango          Tiny           Pink Mango Tiny
```

**Question 2:** I need to extract "n_col3" from n_col1 & n_col2 but that should be similar to the column_3 of data frame 1. *(see the brackets for info of what to be extracted)*

**Note**: If all the information of Column_3 is not available in Column_1 & Column_2 like in Row 1 & Row 3, Only that information that is available should be extracted)

DF2 =

```
  n_col1                     n_col2                    n_col3
L854 fruit Charlie      Green LTD Large      fruit Large(Green missing Fruit Large extracted)
Red alpha 8 small       Tango G250 Apple     Red Apple small(all information extracted)
Mk43 Mango Beta         Tiny J448 T          Mango Tiny(Pink missing, Mango Tiny is extracted)
M40 Yellow Medium       Romeo Banana         Yellow Banana Medium(all information extracted)
```

I want to extract that column so that I can do further processing of merging. Can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: as your columns are simply strings, try `df['col3] = df['Column_1'] + ' ' + df['Column_2']`

Comment: if you will have any int's or floats in the columns, just add `.astype(str)` to each

Comment: for mutiple cols, use `df['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].astype(str).agg(' '.join, axis=1)`

Comment: @NoobVB But that would not merge the columns. the third column of the second dataframe should depend on the values present in the first data frame. Somehow just producing the common values

Comment: merging is done on Unique values, usually something you can call ID.  Once you combine columns as you wanted, you should check if you can use `pd.merge` option